# How to Fatal Error in Wordpess and Xampp Server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Error message is like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'wordpress.wp_options' doesn't exist in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:2056 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2056): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT option_n...') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php(1945): wpdb->_do_query('SELECT option_n...') #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php(2695): wpdb->query('SELECT option_n...') #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\option.php(284): wpdb->get_results('SELECT option_n...') #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php(1730): wp_load_alloptions() #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\load.php(752): is_blog_installed() #6 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed() #7 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php(96): require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #8 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php(50): require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #9 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #10 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #11 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2056

My database name is WordPress and password is null. And when I try to go through the localhost/wordpress/ the error above is shown.

Comment: `Table 'wordpress.wp_options' doesn't` please check your table if it exist in your database or check the spelling of the tablename in your code.

Comment: As my database table name is wordpress .So then what to change. Or what?

Comment: Do you have a `wp_options` table in your `wordpress` database? Kindly check.

Comment: Or you can post a screenshot of your database tables so we can see if that `wp_options` table is really there.

Comment: as screenshot is not able to attached in comment so in a answer form it is attached below please see it and follow up be soon. For provide me your private communication id so that i can get connected to you,

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?